# PACKAGE_ADDED in BroadcastReceiver doesn't work

Tags: android

Have this code: http://pastebin.com/WVFPKmw9

But it does not work. It works only when it is replaced but not when installed. Did I do something wrong?

I did it on pastebin because I said it was a lot of code to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) mentions

```
Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.
```

Can you try installing any other application after you installed your app ?

Comment: oh, I thought that the signal is received by installing the same application. And how I can know if the completed application be installed?

Comment: There is no way you could get notified when your app is successfully installed. By default an application is in the STOPPED state when it is installed and it is moved out of that state on explicit action of the user to start the app ie., there is no way you can get your app code executed until user's explicitly starts it. Juts to understand, why do you want to know when the application is installed ?

Comment: is to start the application service, but you're right, there is no need, I will modify my application so that it does not depend on explicit but to start manually.